# Brand new looking for direction on PDF Page remover

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have been looking for a basic PDF page remover. What I am looking for is something that will let me put in the page numbers I want removed from the file I select. Still really new I am reading a few books to learn, but wanting to use this to make my job a bit easier as the current program is very stupid where I have to make sure to remember to subtract a number from the page given due to how PDF is.

I have to basic codes I would love some critical review of so I can hopefully refine it and make it to something that is easy to use. I thank anyone for their time and help loving how python reads and feels.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pages_delete = [4]

input = PdfFileReader('example.pdf', 'rb')
output = PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
    if i not in pages_delete:

p = input.getPage(i)

output.addPage(p)

with open('pages_deleted.pdf', 'wb') as f:

output.write(f)
```

this is the second one

```
import PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
pdf1File = open('*file_name*')
pdf1Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf1File)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for pageNum in range(pdf1Reader.numPages):
        pageObj - pdf1Reader.getPage(pageNum)
        pdfWriter.removePage(pageObj)

pdfOutputFile = open('*filename*-Edit')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
pdfOutFile.close()
```

Comment: It seems this is already working code and you are asking for someone to review it. Stack Overflow is about *specific* questions and *specific* problems. It is, unfortunately, not for asking for open-ended suggestions to your code. For that, I advise taking a look at another site on the SE network: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is a "*is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.*". Take a look at their [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for posting guidelines.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! All help is welcomed =)!